# Numpy: use bins with infinite range

Tags: python, numpy, range, infinite, bin

In my Python script I have floats that I want to bin. Right now I'm doing:

```
min_val = 0.0
max_val = 1.0
num_bins = 20
my_bins = numpy.linspace(min_val, max_val, num_bins)
hist,my_bins = numpy.histogram(myValues, bins=my_bins)
```

But now I want to add two more bins to account for values that are < 0.0 and for those that are > 1.0. One bin should thus include all values in ( -inf, 0), the other one all in [1, inf)

Is there any straightforward way to do this while still using numpy's `histogram` function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `numpy.histogram()` happily accepts infinite values in the `bins` argument:

```
numpy.histogram(my_values, bins=numpy.r_[-numpy.inf, my_bins, numpy.inf])
```

Alternatively, you could use a combination of `numpy.searchsorted()` and `numpy.bincount()`, though I don't see much advantage to that approach.

Comment: With matplotlib (`plt`), even though it uses numpy's `hist` internally, it does not accept the `inf` (drawing infinite boxes is too much? :-)). But a VERY large value (compared to the typical range of my data) worked well in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `numpy.inf` as the upper and `-numpy.inf` as the lower bin limits.

Answer (score 0):

With Numpy version 1.16 you have `histogram_bin_edges`. With this, todays solution calls `histogram_bin_edges` to get the bins, `concatenate` -inf and +inf and pass this as bins to `histogram`:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,7,4,6,7,5,4,3,2,3]
np.histogram(a, bins=np.concatenate(([np.NINF], np.histogram_bin_edges(a), [np.PINF])))
```

Results in:

```
(array([0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2]),
array([-inf,  1. ,  1.6,  2.2,  2.8,  3.4,  4. ,  4.6,  5.2,  5.8,  6.4, 7. ,  inf]))
```

if you prefer to have the last bin empty (as I do), you can use the `range` parameter and add a small number to `max`:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,2,3,4,7,4,6,7,5,4,3,2,3]
np.histogram(a, bins=np.concatenate(([np.NINF], np.histogram_bin_edges(a, range=(np.min(a), np.max(a)+.1)), [np.PINF])))
```

Results in:

```
(array([0, 1, 3, 0, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]),
array([-inf, 1.  , 1.61, 2.22, 2.83, 3.44, 4.05, 4.66, 5.27, 5.88, 6.49, 7.1 ,  inf]))
```